# Find element in selenium for LinkedIn Job Page

Tags: selenium

I am currently trying to scrape jobs on Linkedin
i have written this code

```
job = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
c = []
​
for i in job:
    c.append(i.text)
print(c)
print((len(c)))
```

This does not return correct output, I would like to retrieve the job title of every posting, the output this is giving me is

```
['LinkedIn', 'new feed updates notifications\nHome', 'My Network', 'Jobs', 'Messaging', '1\n1 new notification\nNotifications', '', '', 'Global Analytic Insights Consultant', 'Concentrix', '6 alumni work here', '', 'Data Intelligence Engineer', 'Arrow Electronics', '', 'Junior Data Modeler', 'Teradata', '1 alum works here', '', 'Research Analyst - BASES', 'NielsenIQ', '1 alum works here', '', 'Group Visualisation and Reporting Specialist', 'Coca-Cola Beverages South Africa (CCBSA)', '', 'Group External Commercial Data Specialist', 'Coca-Cola Beverages South Africa (CCBSA)', '', 'Junior/ Business Analyst', 'Arrow Electronics', '', 'Technical Consultant (O365)', 'Microsoft', '2 connections work here', '', 'Business Analyst', '', 'Support Engineer for Power BI', 'Microsoft', '2 connections work here', '', 'Insights and Analytics Specialist', 'Souq.com', '', 'Call Center Representative', 'Raya CX', '', 'Work from Home Opportunities | Flexible Hours', 'Appen', '', 'Early Careers Program', 'DXC Technology', '1 alum works here', '', 'Business Intelligence Executive', 'noon', '', 'Performance Management Analyst', 'talabat', '7 alumni work here', '', 'IT Business Analyst', 'ALEXBANK', '30 alumni work here', '', 'Study Abroad', 'Educatly', '', 'Work from Home Opportunities | Flexible Hours', 'Appen', '', 'Associate Managing Consultant, Advisors', 'Mastercard', '', 'Assistant', 'NielsenIQ', '', 'Program Support Associate', 'Souq.com', '', 'Junior/ Business Analyst', 'Arrow Electronics', '', 'Internet Analyst', 'Appen', '', 'Oracle Cloud SCM / ERP Junior Coordinator (12 months contract)', 'Oracle', '1 connection works here', 'Try Premium for free', 'About', 'Accessibility', 'Help Center', 'Ad Choices', 'Advertising', '', '', '', '', '']
101
```

Here is a link for the page:

linkedin.com/jobs/search/?geoId=106155005&location=Egypt

Comment: Kindly look for the unique attribute/class your desired scrapping element belongs to. If multiple segments belong to same class then you can use list[i] to get it followed after your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using a wrong locator.
There are a lot of elements with a tag name `a` on that page, most of them are not what you are looking for.
This is why you getting this result.
**UPD**
This code should work:

```py
job_titles = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.job-card-list__title")
c = []
​
for title in job_titles:
    c.append(title.text)
print(c)
print((len(c)))
```

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?geoId=106155005&location=Egypt here is a link to the page please tell me how I can do it

Comment: Please see the updated answer. Let me know if there are still problems / questions

Comment: This is the output it gives ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
25

Comment: @Prophet you need to change the for loop ```for title in job_titles:
    c.append(title.text)```

Comment: oh it did! thank you so much! can you please explain to me what you did, because I still need to scrape other things like the title and the details of each job on the right side of the page

Comment: and do you know how i can make selenium open each page and scrape it automatically

Comment: What exactly do you want me to explain?

Comment: Not anymore prophet i got what you did thank you!

Comment: Can you please help me on this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69109163/make-selenium-scroll-linkedin-to-scrape-jobs

Comment: @SeifMahdi I saw that post. The problem in that case that there are 8 pages, then `...` and finally page 40 there. In case it was a `next` page button I would give you relatively simple solution, but without it it makes more complex logic...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69111440/linkedin-pagination-to-scrap-jobs/69112962#69112962

Comment: I found a way to do it here but it is giving me an error

Answer (score 0):

These is CSS - get the text from it:
`.disabled.ember-view.job-card-container__link.job-card-list__title`
Looks like its better to scroll down to the bottom of the page in order to load all the jobs because there is 25 at page and when you open the page you see only 7, so better to scroll down and than search for the title

if you want Xpath:
`//a[@class="disabled ember-view job-card-container__link job-card-list__title"]`

Comment: Can you please write the piece of code so I can get it better?

Comment: @SeifMahdi as Prophet wrote it's ok, just need to update the for loop

Comment: Can you please help me on this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69109163/make-selenium-scroll-linkedin-to-scrape-jobs