# Make Selenium scroll LinkedIn to scrape jobs

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this code scraping each job title and company name from :

```
https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?geoId=106155005&location=Egypt
```

This is for every job title

```
job_titles = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.job-card-list__title")
c = []

for title in job_titles:
    c.append(title.text)
print(c)
print((len(c)))
```

This is for every company name

```
Company_Names = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.job-card-container__company-name")
d = []

for name in Company_Names:
    d.append(name.text)
print(d)
print((len(d)))
```

I provided the URL above, there are many many pages!
how can I make Selenium auto-open each page and scrape each of the 4 thousand results available?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to paginate to each page, but I am yet to know how to scrape each page.
So the URL is :

```
 https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?geoId=106155005&location=Egypt&start=25
```

The start parameter in the URL increments by 25 from each page to the other.
so we add this piece of code which navigates us successfully to the other pages:

```
page = 25 
pagination = browser.get('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?geoId=106155005&location=Egypt&start={}'.format(page))
for i in range(1,40):
    page =  i * 25 
    pagination = browser.get('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?geoId=106155005&location=Egypt&start={}'.format(page
```